# Can I set null as the default value for a @Value in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I'm currently using the @Value Spring 3.1.x annotation like this:

```
@Value("${stuff.value:}")
private String value;
```

This puts an empty String into the variable if the attribute is not present. I would like to have null as the default instead of an empty String. Of course I also want to avoid an error when the property stuff.value is not set.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You must set the nullValue of the [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html#setNullValue%28java.lang.String%29). For the example I'm using the string `@null` but you can also use the empty string as nullValue.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <!-- config the location(s) of the properties file(s) here -->
    <property name="nullValue" value="@null" />
</bean>
```

Now you can use the string `@null` to represent the `null` value

```
@Value("${stuff.value:@null}")
private String value;
```

Please note: The context name space doesn't support the null value at the moment. You can't use

```
<context:property-placeholder null-value="@null" ... />
```

Tested with Spring 3.1.1

Comment: What's Java configuration equivalent of this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347929/spring-set-a-property-only-if-the-value-is-not-null mentions using ${some.param:#{null}}, and that worked for me without having to set nullValue, seems that this is the default? (In a Spring Boot application.)

Comment: Simple use power of SPEL ${stuff.value:#{null}}  as suggested by  vorburger and in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735141/specify-default-property-value-as-null-in-spring

Comment: seems much less configuration is required for ben3000 and JRichardsz answers.

Comment: there is a newer way to set `null` as default, see the most up'ed answer here

Answer (score 352):

This is really old, but you can use Spring EL now, e.g.

```java
@Value("${stuff.value:#{null}}")
private String stuffValue;
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735141/specify-default-property-value-as-null-in-spring).

Comment: This should be chosen as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 93):

Thanks to @vorburger:

```
@Value("${email.protocol:#{null}}")
String protocol;
```

will set the string value at **null** without any other configurations.

Comment: worked in spring-boot last 2019 version: 2.1.7.RELEASE ... https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Also works in Spring Boot 2.5.6

Comment: Also works with Spring boot 2.6.2!

Comment: Seems not to be working with Spring Boot's `@ConditionalOnExpression`.

Answer (score 2):

I give @nosebrain credit as I did not know about "null-value" but I prefer to avoid using null values altogether particularly since its difficult to represent `null` in a properties file.

But here is an alternative using null with out `null-value` so it will work with what ever property placeholder.

```
public class MyObject {

   private String value;

   @Value("${stuff.value:@null}")
   public void setValue(String value) {
      if ("@null".equals(value)) this.value = null;
      else this.value = value;
   }
}
```

Personally I prefer my way because maybe later on you want `stuff.value` to be a Comma-separated-value or perhaps to Enum the switch is easier. Its also easier to unit test :)

**EDIT: based on your comments on using enums and my opinion of not using null.**

```
@Component
public class MyObject {

    @Value("${crap:NOTSET}")
    private Crap crap;

    public enum Crap {
        NOTSET,
        BLAH;
    }
}
```

The above works fine for me. You avoid null. If your property files want to explicit set that they don't want to handle it then you do (*but you don't even have to specify this as it will default to NOTSET*).

```
crap=NOTSET
```

`null` is very bad and is different than `NOTSET`. It means spring or unit test did not set it which is why there is IMHO a difference. I still would probably use the setter notation (previous example) as its easier to unit test (private variables are hard to set in a unit test).

Comment: The String value was an example, I really needed this for an Enum value, where an empty String just causes a conversion error. With the @null you can have a null as "no Enum set", which is what I need.

Comment: All the more reason why I would not recommend null but instead some enum that represents not set.

Comment: That would require putting Enum.NOTSET into all properties files (>30), which seems a lot of work with almost no benefits...

Comment: I haven't tried this but in theory wouldn't `@Value("${stuff.value:NOTSET}")` work?

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution. Unfortunately I can't change the enum (dep), so I have to go with null. Otherwise you are right, the NOTSET would work.

Comment: How about assigning an integer value?

     @Value("${datasource.connections:5}")
     private Integer connections;

would this work?

Answer (score -1):

In case you need to inject an empty (0 length) "" string as @Value default - use SPEL (spring expression language) as follows:

```
@Value("${index.suffix:#{''}}") 
private String indexSuffix;
```

#{''} just gets you an empty string as injected @Value's default.

by yl

Comment: the initial
`@Value("${stuff.value:}")
private String value;`
does exactly the same and is preferred way of doing it.
Anyway your reply does not answer the question.