# Specify default property value as NULL in Spring

Tags: spring, properties, null, default-value

I want to define default property value in Spring XML configuration file. I want this default value to be `null`.

Something like this:

```
...
<ctx:property-placeholder location="file://${configuration.location}" 
                          ignore-unresolvable="true" order="2" 
                          properties-ref="defaultConfiguration"/>

<util:properties id="defaultConfiguration">
    <prop key="email.username" >
        <null />
    </prop>  
    <prop key="email.password">
        <null />
    </prop>  
</util:properties>
...
```

This doesn't work. Is it even possible to define `null` default values for properties in Spring XML configuration?

Comment: You answered your own question. Use <null />

Comment: It doesn't work this way:  
 `Invalid content starting with element 'null'. No child element is expected at this point.`

Comment: i don't think you can do that. Maybe removing those properties will be enough. Java Properties returns null if a property is not defined.

Comment: If property is missing in the property file and I don't define default value, problem arises when I try to reference this missing property:  
`Could not resolve placeholder 'email.username' in string value "${email.username}"`

Comment: You could use ${email.username:null} to set null as the default, although that may give you the string "null". Or, if you are using @Value, you could add @Autowired(required = false), then any missing properties will be set to null.

Comment: I think you cant define property as null and use property placeholders in XML. Properties will return null if property is not exists, and if you return null this will mean what Spring also treat it if property not exists. I think this is also related to https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7294

Answer (score 109, accepted):

It is better to use Spring EL in such way

```
<property name="password" value="${email.password:#{null}}"/>
```

it checks whether `email.password` is specified and sets it to `null` (not `"null"` String) otherwise

Comment: Perfect!  Does this introduce a dependency on spring-el?

Comment: Amazing! For those that didn't know this also works with Spring Annotations. @Value("${email.password:#{null}}") private String password;

Answer (score 4):

You can try use Spring EL.

```
<prop key="email.username">#{null}</prop>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `prop` doesn't have `value` attribute.
I think that if there is a solution, something else than `prop` has to be used.

Comment: You can place EL between tags, modified anwser.

Comment: This way it throws NPE  
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 4):

have a look at [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#setNullValue(String)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html#setNullValue%28java.lang.String%29)

It states that:

> By default, no such null value is defined. This means that there is no way to express null as a property value unless you explictly map a corresponding value

So just define the string "null" to map the null value in your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="nullValue" value="null"/>
    <property name="location" value="testing.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Now you can use it in your properties files:

```
db.connectionCustomizerClass=null
db.idleConnectionTestPeriod=21600
```

Comment: This also means that you will not be allowed to use the String "null"

Comment: Let's be honest though, who sets an explicit `"null"` string instead of `null`?

Comment: Hibernate property db.connectionCustomizerClass: I want to either set com.mchange.v2.c3p0.example.InitSqlConnectionCustomizer, or null. Setting is configured via Maven filtering.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you can do the following:

```
@Value("${some.value:null}")
private String someValue;
```

and

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfig() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setNullValue("null");
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```