# Spring Boot Maven Build Problem with Random Values in application.properties

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have edited, for example, application.properties from

```
spring.mail.host=stmp.test.com
```

to

```
spring.mail.host=${server.mail.host}
```

and I override at starttime these properties to the correct values. This works fine until I want to run maven to build my application.

I receive the following Exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class
```

I think the problem is that maven also needs these values but how and where can I insert them? I dont want to run mvn on the cli.

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/passing-command-line-arguments-from-maven-as-properties-in-pom-xml)?

Comment: First, thanks to your answer. I don't want any credentials in my source code and the pom.xml is also part of that. I will upload this project to git later and therefore I need the possibility to config from outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @[Nicholas K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6139527/nicholas-k) was making the point that you can pass in those values in you maven command. For example with the argument `mvn spring-boot:run "-Dserver.mail.host=mailhost"`.

You can also set an environment variable and that should be injected:

`export SERVER_MAIL_HOST=mailhost`

Or if you sometimes don't want to set them you could set a default for the property in your properties file:

`spring.mail.host=${server.mail.host:defaultmailhost}`

Or [default it to an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991194/can-i-set-null-as-the-default-value-for-a-value-in-spring)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to create under the tab environment all these variables. Without any luck. After that I created all env environment variables with export ... also without any luck. Same Exception. I also tried it on the cli without any luck. This is insane.
Not quite sure why it is so hard to run a maven build only with some parameters which should be overwritten.

Comment: Could it be a different issue like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375016/failed-to-process-import-candidates-for-configuration-class ? That failed to process import candidates message isn't necessarily related. Perhaps you can post more of your stacktrace

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.skidata.hosting.certselfservice.CertSelfServiceApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderAutoConfiguration
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:648) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.lambda

Comment: If you try setting the defaults for the values does it still fail?

Comment: Yes, with the default values its working fine and I can build the application again. Thanks so far, but now I have the passwords again in the file which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: You should also be able to override the whole properties file by putting a different on in a /config/ directory alongside your jar - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Also perhaps try "spring.mail.host=${SERVER_MAIL_HOST:defaultmailhost}" in the properties file

Comment: I will check that out. Thanks again!