# How can I understand whether a bean exists in runtime?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

For example, I have a class

```
public class Car{
     private Motor motor;

     public void setMotor(Motor motor){
          this.motor = motor;
     }   
}
```

My bean looks like

```
<bean id="car" class="Car">
    <property name="motor" ref="${motorProvider.getAvailableMotor()}"/>
</bean>
```

This method:     `motorProvider.getAvailableMotor()` returns a bean name(string), of which motor I should use.

But there can be a situation when such bean(with such name) is not created. How can I check it?

Comment: try: https://code.google.com/p/openpojo/

Comment: What is the point to know whether the bean is in the context? Can you do something useful when it doesn't exist?

Comment: @AaronDigulla If it is not exist, then I will set something default value.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are several patterns how to do this. Here is one I often use:

```
public class Car{
     private Motor motor;

     @Autowired
     private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
        try {
            motor = applicationContext.getBean( Motor.class );
        } catch( NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e ) {
            motor = new DefaultMotor();
        }
     }
}
```

Note you could also call `applicationContext.containsBeanDefinition(name)` but that would search your context twice (once in `containsBeanDefinition()` and then second time when you call `getBean()`) so catching the exception is usually faster.

Since we catch a specific exception that says "bean doesn't exist", using `if`/`else` has almost no advantage anymore.

Comment: It looks interesting, I will try it

Comment: I recommend using this instead of validating by throwing an exception
if(appContext.containsBeanDefinition(w.getName()));

Comment: @Sridhar Than I have to search the context twice for the bean. This is more expensive (the larger the context is), than handling the exception.

Comment: @aaron in that case you can try to use containsBeanDefinition

Answer (score 3):

SPeL; something like:

```
<property name="motor" value="#(if(${motorProvider} != null) ${motorProvider.getAvailableMotor()})"/>
```

I think it was discussed also here: [Spring - set a property only if the value is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347929/spring-set-a-property-only-if-the-value-is-not-null) . As they said before for more information see: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html

Comment: I think, you don't don't understand me right) I don't want to check something on null, I want to understand is there such bean in my context. Because if such bean is not created, spring will cause an exception