# Spring SpEL - set a property only if the value is not null

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I'm using Spring and I want to set a property only if the value passed is not null?

I tried this example but it doesn't work.
I want to add the property only if it is not null else not add it.
I don't want to add a default value.
Thanks for your help

```
<util:properties id="mailProperties" location="classpath:mail.properties"/>
  <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">#{mailProperties['mail.smtp.starttls.enable']:''}</prop>             
           </props>
    </property>
```

Comment: See the veeery closely related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347929/spring-set-a-property-only-if-the-value-is-not-null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#{mailProperties['mail.smtp.starttls.enable']==null ? false: mailProperties['mail.smtp.starttls.enable']}
```

Here is an example To set a default value: if value is null I set it to false else I set it to its value.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you want something like this

```
${mail.smtp.starttls.enable:defaultValue}
```

For more details:
[Is there a way to specify a default property value in Spring XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513484/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-default-property-value-in-spring-xml)

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4785